# Add logos beyond the title (tikzposter)

Tags: graphics, logos, tikzposter

I am very new to `tikzposter` framework and struggling with adding logos to my title. I need to create similar to the picture attached. Using the "Default" theme, I need to put two (or three) different logos on each side of the poster.

[image]

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

UPD, the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[25pt,a0paper,landscape,margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\usetheme{Default} % See Section 5
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\title{Very long title which will be very useful}
\institute{institute}
\author{Author} 


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{0.33}
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext} % See Section 4.2
\column{0.33}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.33}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to lay the foundation for a solution through what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It helps those interested in providing a solution get to it faster, hitting the ground running. Please do so in order to speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I assumed that such a basic "poster" might be done in a second, since it's straightforward.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I redefined \maketitle to name the title node and then used this named node to place two additional nodes with the logos. All you have to do is to use your images and options in `\insertlogoi`, `\insertlogoii`:

```
\insertlogoi[<options>]{<logo1 file>}
\insertlogoii[<options>]{<logo2 file>}
```

and you can control the separation between the logos and the title box using `\LogoSep` (default value=`0pt`).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{0pt}

\insertlogoi[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\insertlogoii[width=5cm]{example-image-b}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };

    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}

    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle

    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
        (title)
        {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoii};

    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

To add three or more logos, one can define similar commands and `\node`s to the ones I defined for the case of two logos. Alittle variation for four logos:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoiii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoiii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoiv[2][]{\def\@insertlogoiv{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoHSep
\newlength\LogoVSep

\setlength\LogoHSep{60pt}
\setlength\LogoVSep{1cm}

\insertlogoi[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\insertlogoii[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\insertlogoiii[width=5cm]{example-image-c}
\insertlogoiv[width=5cm]{example-image}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };

    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}

    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle

    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
        (title)
        {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west]
      at ([shift={(-\LogoHSep,\LogoVSep)}]title.west)
      (logo1)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west,right=of logo1] 
      (logo2)
      {\@insertlogoii};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
      at ([shift={(\LogoHSep,\LogoVSep)}]title.east)
      (logo4)
      {\@insertlogoiv};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,left=of logo4] 
      (logo4)
      {\@insertlogoiii};

    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One more question: If I need to put more logos (two logos from each side), how should I change the code? Thnx!

Comment: @ArnoldKlein Your reputation is enough to accept the answer :) I thank you also for the interest in up-voting, which you can already do also. Give me some minutes to add some code for four logos. How would you like them to be. At each side one column with two logos or one row with the two logos?

Comment: Indeed! I can vote now. One row with two logos. Thnx!

Comment: I tried to add another \node, but it did not work :(

\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoii};
      
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoiii};

Comment: I need to use \columns or to shift slightly the additional \node

Comment: @ArnoldKlein See the example code at the bottom in my updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

A somewhat dirty, but very flexible way to insert logos using a "low-level" tikz command referencing the name of the title node:

```
\node[OPTIONS] at (TP@title.west) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{mylogo.png}};
```

Here you can provide additional options to the node command so as to move your logo wherever you need. Also, you can change `west` in `(TP@title.west)` to other positions. An example document:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title} 
\author{Author} 
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\node[anchor=west] at (TP@title.west) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{mylogo1.png}};
\node[anchor=west,yshift=-2cm] at (TP@title.west) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{mylogo2.png}};
\node[anchor=east,yshift=-1cm] at (TP@title.east) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{mylogo3.png}};

\block{Block}{Content}
\end{document}
```

(embarrassing to say that I'm one of the authors of tikzposter and was now googling myself for how to insert a logo without having to redefine any macro. As a result I came up with this solution.)

Comment: I like this solution because of its flexibility. +1

Comment: Saved my (insert something) for the NeurIPS poster...+1

Comment: @Elena Is there anywhere available a documentation for the names of these low-level nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am not such a low-level Latex expert. There are nodes/coordinates blockbody, blocktitle, innerblockbody, innerblocktitle, notecenter, notetarget (of the last created ones). Probably the following macros \titleposleft,\titleposbottom, \titleposright,\titlepostop. The node TP@title (but I don't even know where I took it from last time). If you have access to the file `tikzposter.dtx`, you could see all the code there.