# Tikzposter: topright works but no topleft?

Tags: tikzposter

I need to place images at the top corners of my poster. Quite surprisingly, `at (topright)` is known, but `(topleft)` is an unknown shape. How so?

Full line (working):

`\node[inner sep=0pt, below left, outer sep=0cm] (logo) at (topright)
    {\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{logo}};`

Full line (not working):

`\node[inner sep=0pt, below left, outer sep=0cm] (logo) at (topleft)
    {\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{logo}};`

Comment: Maybe help:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489933/31034

Comment: Please post a MWE. Also, should below left be below right in the second code line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because `tikzposter` doesn't define `topleft`, only `topright` and `bottomleft`. That's why it doesn't work.

You can define the missing corner coordinates yourself with e.g.

```
\coordinate (topleft)     at (topright -| bottomleft);
\coordinate (bottomright) at (topright |- bottomleft);
```

Or use `(topright -| bottomleft)` directly.

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}

\begin{document}    
\coordinate (topleft)     at (topright -| bottomleft);
\coordinate (bottomright) at (topright |- bottomleft);

\node[inner sep=0pt, below left] (logoa) at (topright) {\includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image-a}};

\node[inner sep=0pt, below right] (logob) at (topleft) {\includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image-b}};

\node[inner sep=0pt, above right] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image-c}};

\node[inner sep=0pt, above left] at (bottomright) {\includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image}};

\end{document}
```

[image]