# QR code on the side of the title of a TikZ poster with Desert theme

Tags: posters, tikzposter, qrcode

Below is the minimal working example reproducing my tikzposter, which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to put a QR code on the right and one on the left of the title. Doesn't need to be very large, just slightly smaller than the height of the blue title box. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=5mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, subcolspace=-.5cm]{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{University}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usetheme{Desert}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block[bodyoffsety=1.5cm,
  titleoffsety=1.5cm]{Abstract}{Abstract goes here}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5} % left column
    \block{Block 1}{Block 1 text}
    \block{Block 2}{Block 2 text}
    \block{Block 3}{Block 3 text}
    \column{0.5} % right column
    \block{Block 4}{Block 4 text}
    \block{Block 5}{Block 5 text}
    \block{Bibliography}{Bibliography goes here}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

## Update after comment

I have updated the code following the Stackexchange post suggested in the comment:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=5mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, subcolspace=-.5cm]{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{University}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{-70pt}

\insertlogoi[width=6cm]{qrcode}
\insertlogoii[width=6cm]{qrcode}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };

    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}

    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle

    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
        (title)
        {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoii};

    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{qrcode} % Add this to your preamble

\usetheme{Desert}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block[bodyoffsety=1.5cm,
  titleoffsety=1.5cm]{Abstract}{Abstract goes here}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5} % left column
    \block{Block 1}{Block 1 text}
    \block{Block 2}{Block 2 text}
    \block{Block 3}{Block 3 text}
    \column{0.5} % right column
    \block{Block 4}{Block 4 text}
    \block{Block 5}{Block 5 text}
    \block{Bibliography}{Bibliography goes here}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have pictures of your qr codes, you can directly use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263564/36296 If you don't have pictures, you can redefine `\insertlogoi` and `\insertlogoii` with whatever package you use to generate qr codes

Comment: About your edit: tikzposter sets the whole poster in as one big tikz picture. You shouldn't nest tikzpictures!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I ended up using the answer in that question, thank you! One thing is that I would like to have one word under each QR code. E.g. "code" and "paper" under the left and right one respectively. Do you know how I could adapt the code for that?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you adapted the code?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done!

Comment: Quick hack: https://pastebin.com/8he9JUgT

Answer (score 1):

With TikZPoster's `\settitle` command it is possible to redefine the title layout.

The example below is based on the default setting (see TikZPoster manual) and inserts QR codes at the outer ends of the title block, both automatically scaled to fit within the predefined margins of the title block (to be adjusted with option `innersep` if desired, see manual):

```
\makettitle[innersep=...]
```

Package `pst-barcode` should be preferred over `qrcode` for its better output quality (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/710114), but here, we use `qrcode` as in the question.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=5mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, subcolspace=-.5cm]{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{University}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usetheme{Desert}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define left and right title graphics (two QR codes), at their default size
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{qrcode}
%\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\newcommand\titlegraphicLeft{%
  \qrcode{https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode}%
%  \makebox[1in][l]{\rule{0pt}{1in}%
%    \psbarcode{https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode}{width=1 height=1}{qrcode}%
%  }%
}
\newcommand\titlegraphicRight{%
  \qrcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/710219}%
%  \makebox[1in][l]{\rule{0pt}{1in}%
%    \psbarcode{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/710219}{width=1 height=1}{qrcode}%
%  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% redefine poster title based on default implementation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\settitle{%
  %rescale and insert left QR
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight+\depth}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\resizebox*{!}{\titleheight-2\titleinnersep}{\titlegraphicLeft}}}%
  %insert title matter
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight+\depth}{\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \vbox{%
        \centering%
        \color{titlefgcolor}%
        {\bfseries\Huge\sc\@title\par}%
        \vspace*{1em}%
        {\huge \@author\par}%
        \vspace*{1em}%
        {\LARGE \@institute}%
    }%
  }}%
  %rescale and insert right QR
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight+\depth}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\resizebox*{!}{\titleheight-2\titleinnersep}{\titlegraphicRight}}}%
}%
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block[bodyoffsety=1.5cm,
  titleoffsety=1.5cm]{Abstract}{Abstract goes here}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5} % left column
    \block{Block 1}{Block 1 text}
    \block{Block 2}{Block 2 text}
    \block{Block 3}{Block 3 text}
    \column{0.5} % right column
    \block{Block 4}{Block 4 text}
    \block{Block 5}{Block 5 text}
    \block{Bibliography}{Bibliography goes here}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```